# Using a link server in SQL Server with failover

Tags: sql-server-2008

Does anybody knows how to create a link server in SQL Server 2008 R2 using failover option?
Thank you.

Comment: we already have a server configured with mirroring, I just want to run a query from another server using a link server. Because I have a mirror configured, I want to make sure to query into Principal or in case of error, goes to the mirror server

Comment: I think your comment is a much better representation of what you're looking for than your original question. I suggest incorporating the comment into the question...

Answer (score 0):

I already found the solution!

I need to add a parameter @catalog

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'MyLinkServer', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'SQLOLEDB', @provstr=N'Server=PRINCIPAL;FailoverPartner=SECONDARY;', @catalog='MyDatabaseName'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it is also important to note that using IP addresses for the servers may not work even though IP addresses did work from SSMS or any other connection string.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
     @server = N'MyLinkServer'
   , @srvproduct=N''
   , @provider=N'SQLNCLI'
   , @provstr=N'Server=principal.server.name.not.IP.address;FailoverPartner=secondary.server.name.not.IP.address;'
   , @catalog='MyDatabaseName'
```